# Eclipse context menue options are missing

Tags: eclipse

I am running Eclipse 3.6.
I used to have two options in the context menu when right clicking a project in any perspective - One would open Windows explorer in the folder the project is located at and the other would open a windows command prompt in the folder the project is located at.

Not sure why but for some reason I don't see these options anymore.
I tried looking for them under "Customize perspective..." but couldn't find it anywhere.

Anyone knows how to restore these two options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse itself does not have this function. So, I think you were using a plugin. I searched the eclipse plugin site, I think you can try this:

http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=1821

Comment: Why thank you. I don't remember using a dedicated plugin for this although I do use to play around with plugins so this was probably exposed through one of the ones I have uninstalled like you say. I tried the one you provided and it seems to be doing what I'm after so thank you again.